# How to make OleDbConnection release file handle

Tags: c#, ms-access, connection

I tried to close OleDbConnection object after using it to create a MDB file, so that I can move the file somewhere else. I put this code at the end of the method

```
            //Close The Connection So that the file can be access. 
            OleDbConnection.ReleaseObjectPool();
            sceConnection.Close();
            sceConnection.Dispose();
```

But it didn't work. I still get msg: The file is being used by another process.

Comment: Hi, Can you show more of your code.

Comment: This code should close and release file handle check rest of your program code.